# Select specific locked cells, leaving other cells 'unselectable'

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet-protection

In Excel VBA, is there a way to select specific locked cells, while leaving other cells 'unselectable'?

I have an excel sheet, which is protected. I would like to give the user the ability to select specific locked cells within a sheet while at the same time not allowing them to select other locked cells within the same sheet.
Basically I have a small, cell-based calendar, in which I would like them to be able to select specific dates (locked cells) on this small range, however there is no need for them to select any other locked cells within the sheet. Excels Sheet Protection only seems to allow a sheet-wide "Select Lock Cells". If there is a way to accomplish this through VBA I would love to hear about it. I did look over a lot of other posts before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you protect a worksheet, the behaviour in each cell is defined by the `Locked` property. Sample code:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect
ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions 'All the cells can be selected
```

With this code, users can edit `cell A1` but not `cell A2`. Bear in mind that, by default, the `Locked` property is set to `True`.

CLARIFICATION

Protection is applied to the whole worksheet. At the cell level, all what you can do is relying on the `Locked` property. What you cannot get is different behaviours for different (Locked/Unlocked) ranges.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your prompt reply. My apologies for my confusing question. I understand the locked feature, however my issue is i need them all locked, however just a subset of those locked cells i want the user to be able to select, while the other set of locked cells i dont want them to select. Excel provides a 'Select Locked Cells' option when protecting a worksheet, however it is sheet-wide, without the ability to specify a range of locked cells to select, while another range, not to select. Any thoughts?

Comment: @raphuket So... you want all the cells to be locked. Some of them being selectable (but not editable) and other ones not even selectable?

Comment: While its important for them to be able to select this range of locked cells, i need to keep them locked because of the formula contained within those cells should not be altered.

Comment: Exactly. Some of the locked cells should be selectable, other locked cells should not be.

Comment: @raphuket the Locked property applies the rules you set when protecting the sheet. One of these properties is allowing the user to select the cells (both locked and non-locked ones); but if you enable this option, the user would see the formulae in the given cells.

Comment: Yes i am not so concerned for them to see the formula, my concern is that if the cells are unlocked they can accidentally modify them or delete them, rendering the calendar function useless.
One idea i had, was to unlock this set of cells completely (its just a 7 x 6 Range of cells). Then have a hidden, and duplicate range, with the exact same formulas, then should they change or delete any formulas within the original range, i can then copy this 'backup range' set of formulas into the original, using a Worksheet Change event in VBA. I was hoping there was a cleaner way to solve this issue.

Comment: @raphuket I have updated my code, this should allow users to select any cell (locked or not).

Comment: Thanks so much, Im going to give that a try. Much appreciated.

Comment: @raphuket why have you unmarked this answer? Is there any problem? The proposed code delivers exactly what you requested: the worksheet is protected but all the cells are selectable.

Comment: @raphuket well... Within what is possible, as explained: you protect the whole worksheet and the rules apply to the whole worksheet; you cannot select specific conditions for specific ranges (other than by relying on the locked property).

Comment: Hello Sorry for that, perhaps again, my explanation was not clear. On the sheet there is basically an entry form, a Day View Calendar, and a small cell-based month-view calendar. It is this Month View calendar Range that I need the user to be able to select individual cells within this range, while not being able to change the code. The Sheet protected, allowing the user to select, but not change, the formula in these cells works just fine. The issue I am having, is that for other locked cells within the sheet, i dont want them to be able to even select these locked cells.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what i am talking about: [Link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/nz1wd21gqcw3af6/SheetProtectionSample.png [/link]

Comment: @raphuket As said, this cannot be done. The protection is applied to the whole spreadsheet; the only differentiation you can do is via Locked property. If you don't consider this answer worthy (you did know already all what I said), I would delete it as far as now (with the ideas regarding your requirements crystal clear), my answer is: it cannot be done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If i know it cannot be done, then i will try to find a work around like the one i have mentioned above. I really appreciate your time and i have marked it as answered correctly and marked it up. Thanks again for your time :)